# Making multilevel drop down menu appear in a table

Tags: css

My apologies if there's an obvious answer to this or if I use incorrect terms - I don't work with CSS very often.

What I'm working with is a dynamically generated table:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
    .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
    .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
    </style>

      #some would be code here to display column headers; I've omitted it.
        <tr>
        <td class="tg-031e"><input type="checkbox" onclick="showForm()"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">%s</td>
```

Notice I've got a checkbox in one of the cells which calls `showForm()` when it's clicked. That function looks like this:

```
    function showForm() {
document.getElementById("f2").style.display = "block";
```

It makes a multilevel drop down menu in a `<div id="f2" style="display:none">` block suddenly appear. The CSS for the multilevel drop down is:

```
/* Menu Styles */

.third-level-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -150px;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

.third-level-menu > li
{
    height: 30px;
    background: #999999;
}
.third-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.second-level-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

.second-level-menu > li
{
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    background: #999999;
}
.second-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.top-level-menu
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.top-level-menu > li
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #999999;
}
.top-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.top-level-menu li:hover > ul
{
    /* On hover, display the next level's menu */
    display: inline;
}


/* Menu Link Styles */

.top-level-menu a /* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */
{
    font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    
    /* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.top-level-menu a:hover { color: #000000; }
```

And the HTML is a variant of:

```
<ul class="top-level-menu">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Offices</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Chicago</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">New York</a>
                <ul class="third-level-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Book a Meeting</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Seattle</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

(Both of these are from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4ScFz/400/))

Now, the problem is that when the checkbox is checked, and `showForm` is run, the multilevel drop down menu appears, but any levels beyond the root option are obscured by the cell boundaries in which it appears. In other words, when I hover the mouse over the root menu item, the subgroups only appear in the small amount of space between the bottom of the root menu item and the bottom of the cell in which the menu is located. So the menu is limited to the cell that it's in; I've tried changing the opacity of the table, but that didn't help.

Is there a way to foreground the menu, or, alternatively, to keep the table in the background so the menu and all of it's subgroups appear normally?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to apply `position: absolute` to the menu to allow it to render outside the table.

```css
td {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
}

div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Overflowing content</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      Content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```